# hibernate reactive error with JDBC THIN URL

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-reactive

I am trying to hibernate reactive with Oracle 19c.
When I send URL as below, I got an error seems string limitation.
How can I resolve this issue?

DB URL: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCLCDB)))"

ERROR: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 108

below is my code

```
public Mutiny.SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = constructConfiguration();
  StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new ReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings( configuration.getProperties() );
  StandardServiceRegistry registry = builder.build();
  return configuration.buildSessionFactory( registry ).unwrap( Mutiny.SessionFactory.class );
}

private org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration constructConfiguration() {
  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();

  entityTypes().forEach(configuration::addAnnotatedClass);

  // set DB info
  configuration.setProperty(Settings.DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"));
  // it works
  configuration.setProperty(Settings.URL,"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB");
  // it raises the error
  // configuration.setProperty(Settings.URL,"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCLCDB)))");
  configuration.setProperty(Settings.USER, "user"));
  configuration.setProperty(Settings.PASS, "1234"));

  return configuration;
}

private Collection<Class<?>> entityTypes() {
  List<Class<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(TestEntity.class);
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Hibernate Reactive can parse that type of URLs at the moment.

Underneath, Hibernate Reactive uses a Vert.x SQL client. One workaround is to configure the driver yourself implementing the interface `SqlClientPoolConfiguration` and add it as a service to via the `ServiceContributor`.

The process is [the same as the one described in the documentation](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.1/reference/html_single/#_vert_x_instance_service) for `VertxInstance`:

1. Create a class that extends `DefaultSqlClientPoolConfiguration`
2. Override the method `connectOptions(URI uri)`:

   ```java
   public class MyOracleClientPool extends DefaultSqlClientPoolConfiguration {

       @Override
       public SqlConnectOptions connectOptions(URI uri) {
           // Create your own SqlConnectOptions object 
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a service contributor:

   ```java
   public class MyServiceContributor implements ServiceContributor {

      @Override
      public void contribute(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder) {
         serviceRegistryBuilder.addService( SqlClientPoolConfiguration.class, new MyOracleClientPool() );
      }
   }
   ```
4. Add a text file named `org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceContributor` to `/META-INF/services/`:

   ```
   org.myproject.MyServiceContributor
   ```

Some info about `SqlClientPoolOptions` is available in the documentation of the [Vert.x SQL client for Oracle](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-oracle-client/java/#_configuration).